# Generic delegates (C#) in Scala?

Tags: c#, scala, delegates

I wanted to know if there is an equivalent of the C# generic delegates in Scala.

The reference website is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233060.aspx

I'm trying to make a complete comparison between C# and Scala, about (co)(contra)(in)variance.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 3):

Scala doesn't have delegates, but you are free to assign functions/lambdas to variables. Here, normal subtyping rules apply. A function `f: A => B` is a subtype of `g: C => D` if the argument is a supertype `A > C` (contravariance) and the return type is a subtype `B < D` (contravariance). Note that any of those four types might actually be tuples, so that tuple subtyping will be applied in such cases.

Example:

```scala
// two (sub-)types to demonstrate variance
class A()
class B() extends A

var delegate: Option[B => A] = None

// a few simple lambdas that can be assigned
delegate = Some((b: B) => new A())  // invariant
delegate = Some((b: B) => new B())  // return type covariance
delegate = Some((a: A) => new A())  // argument type contravariance
delegate = Some((a: A) => new B())  // co- and contravariance

// can we assign methods to function types? Yes!
class Context(retVal: A) {
    def meth(b: B): A = retVal
}

val ctx = new Context(new A())
delegate = Some(ctx.meth _)  // partial application
delegate = Some(b => ctx.meth(b)) // wrapping in lambda
```

If we add (more) generics, this doesn't change anything since functions already are generic types in Scala. In particular, co- and contravariance for functions is available because functions are actually defined as `trait Function1[-T1, +R]`. User-defined types can also make use of variance when defined properly.